# Flow requiring annotation on object literal

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

Assuming that `cx` is defined as:

```
var cx = require('classnames');
```

… I have the following JSX code:

```
test: function(panelEnabled: boolean) {
    const klass = cx({disabled: !panelEnabled});
    return (<div className={klass}>foo</div>);
},
```

The above results in Flow 0.35.0 complaining with the following message:

```
app/components/target-resolution.js:20
 20:         const klass = cx({disabled: !panelEnabled});
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object literal. Could not decide which case to select
 17:     ...classes: Array<$npm$classnames$Classes>
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ union type. See lib: flow-typed/npm/classnames_v2.x.x.js:17
  Case 2 may work:
    8:   {[className: string]: boolean } |
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: flow-typed/npm/classnames_v2.x.x.js:8
  But if it doesn't, case 3 looks promising too:
    9:   {[className: string]: ?boolean } |
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See lib: flow-typed/npm/classnames_v2.x.x.js:9
  Please provide additional annotation(s) to determine whether case 2 works (or consider merging it with case 3):
   20:         const klass = cx({disabled: !panelEnabled});
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not operator
```

I can work around this issue with either of the below two approaches:

### ugly but doesn't change the API of the method

```
test: function(panelEnabled: boolean) {
    const klassSpec: {disabled: boolean} ={disabled: !panelEnabled}; 
    const klass = cx(klassSpec);
    return (<div className={klass}>foo</div>);
},
```

### shorter but requires changing the API

```
test: function(panelDisabled: boolean) {
    const klass = cx({disabled: panelDisabled});
    return (<div className={klass}>foo</div>);
},
```

I have gotten the libdefs from [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) and the file I am pointed to by the flow message (`flow-typed/npm/classnames_v2.x.x.js`) is a mere 17 lines:

```
// flow-typed signature: 2dfd96b054f56a84f2d08769019d32d7
// flow-typed version: dc0ded3d57/classnames_v2.x.x/flow_>=v0.23.x_<=v0.27.x

type $npm$classnames$Classes =
  string |
  // We need both of these because if we just have the latter it won't accept objects typed
  // explicitly as the former, due to mutation concerns.
  {[className: string]: boolean } |
  {[className: string]: ?boolean } |
  Array<string> |
  false |
  void |
  null

declare module 'classnames' {
  declare function exports(
    ...classes: Array<$npm$classnames$Classes>
  ): string;
}
```

My questions are:

1. what is the cause and significance of this message ?
2. what is the proper way to handle this?
3. why isn't it clear to Flow that if `panelEnabled` is `boolean` then `!panelEnabled` is also boolean.

Comment: Seems like a Flow bug maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have installed the wrong version of the `classnames` definition file.

If you see the commented line in the definition file

```
// flow-typed version: dc0ded3d57/classnames_v2.x.x/flow_>=v0.23.x_<=v0.27.x
```

it indicates that this definition file is compatible with flow >= 0.23 up to flow 0.27.

Maybe you're using an out-dated version of flow-typed? Try updating it with `npm install -g flow-typed`.

I bootstrapped a project from scratch to test your code and it works correctly. Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "flow-classnames",
  "scripts": { "flow": "flow" },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-bin": "^0.35.0"
  }
}
```

and here's my `index.js`

```
// @flow

const cx = require('classnames');

const test = function(panelEnabled: boolean) {
  const klass = cx({disabled: !panelEnabled});
  return (<div className={klass}>foo</div>);
}
```

Steps to test:

```
npm install
flow-typed install
npm run flow
```

No errors!

Comment: I already had `flow-typed` version `2.0.0` installed. I think what happened is that when upgraded my `flow-bin` version from `0.27.0` to `0.35.0` I should also have done a `flow-typed install --overwrite` (which I didn't) as, from what I've gathered so far, `flow-typed` fetches the appropriate libdefs for the version of `flow-bin` declared in your `package.json`. Is that right ?

Comment: That's correct, `flow-typed install` fetches the appropriate libdefs according to your package.json and decides the version of flow based on your `flow-bin` dependency. So yes, you should've run `flow-typed install` after bumping the `flow-bin` dependency.